# How do I add containers/ boxes to my fixed sidebar to have structure like a menu

Tags: html, css, sidebar

[image]my left sidebar has no structure and I want it to be like a menu with a background color. I also have no idea how to make the changes in CSS so I can change the width and height...etc

here is the code for the sidebar

```
<div class="sidebar">

    <nav>
        <h1>Menu</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html"><strong>Home</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="workshop.html"><strong>Workshop </strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="team.html"><strong>Team </strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="resources.html"><strong>Resources </strong></a></li>
<li><a href="publications.html"><strong>Publication </strong></a></li>
<li><a href="opportunities.html"><strong>Opportunities </strong></a></li>

</div><!-- /sidebar -->
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

CSS syntax can be called for in three ways.

1. **Internal CSS**: `<style>` tags, which must be underneath a `<head>` element that precede your `<body>`.
2. **External CSS**: Linking external CSS with just the CSS syntax, void of any HTML tags. You connect the two documents with a `<link>` tag using the `href` attribute
3. **Block-level/Inline elements**: CSS can be placed inside of block-level elements and inline elements ([a list of which appear here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp))

Here is how to color your sidebar's background using the first method:

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .sidebar {
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

And here's one way to add containers/boxes around your sidebar using the first method:

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .box {
      background-color: #eee;
      margin-top: 5px;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .sidebar {
      display: block;
      width: 150px;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    .row:after {
      clear: both;
      content: "";
      display: table;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="box">
        <a href="index.html"><strong>Home</strong></a>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <a href="workshop.html"><strong>Workshop</strong></a>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <a href="team.html"><strong>Team</strong></a>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <a href="resources.html"><strong>Resources </strong></a>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <a href="publications.html"><strong>Publication</strong></a>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <a href="opportunities.html"><strong>Opportunities</strong></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but you can change the font, margins, and padding underneath the `<style>` tag however you want.

Also, I would suggest going through [w3school's CSS introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) just to familiarize yourself with how it all works. Another tip: **Make sure all of your starting tags have the necessary end tags**! For example, in the code you wrote a closing `</ul>` and `</nav>` are missing.